# How to receive images from a user using a GupShup Chatbot via Skype

Tags: chatbot, skype, gupshup

I am currently trying out Gupshup to develop a chatbot that is deployable on several platforms.

**[The Situation]**
One feature of this chatbot requires the user being able to send an image to the chatbot, so that the image can then be further processed on the backend. Looking at the Gupshup docs I have been able to provide this upload feature for a range of channels (Facebook, Slack, Telegram, Chat Widget).

**[The Problem ]**
As stated in the title, I am having trouble with receiving image messages when using the chatbot on **Skype**. After some testing, I was able to see the following problem:

When a user sends an image to the chatbot on Skype, there is **NO EVENT** that is being triggered, which means that my code will not even be executed. Looking at my logs, I simply cannot see any event generated by the user sending an image via Skype.

(Since no event is generated, the "onMessage" function is not called. It does work for text messages AND image messages on the channels listed above, but doesnt seem to work for image messages using skype).

**[My setup]**
 - I am using the in-browser Javascript Gupshup IDE
 - Logging is done via console.log(); 
 - For deploying I use the **"deploy to prod"** option 
 - To use the chatbot, I am currently using the **Gupshup proxy bot**

**[What I have tried so far]**
I tried using different devices as the user (Skype on my Android phone, Skype on ubuntu 16.04, Skype on Win10) but there is no difference in the behavior. Since image messages do not generate an event that is dispatched, my code does not even get executed, which is why I am pretty limited in my possibilities.
 I have also browsed through the Gupshup Docs and could not find any special instructions for Skype as a channel.
Also, I could not find any helpful posts on SO or google.

**[How to repeat my issue]**
  1. Create a Gupshup Bot, using the Javascript IDE as development tool
  2. Add logging to the code, so that ANY incoming is logged
  3. Use the "deploy to prod" functionality
  4. Now open Skype, add the Gupshup proxy bot and use the "proxy YourBotName" functionality
  5. Send an image into the chat 
  6. Now check the chatbot's logs and you will not be able to see any event that was generated by the message.

Has anyone else also experienced this problem? Did you find a solution, or is it simply not supported or maybe a bug on Gupshup? Maybe also Skype recently changed some APIs and Gupshup has not been able to keep up with these changes?
Any help is very welcome!

*[Btw since this is my very first post, feedback on the post's overall form is very welcome as well!]*